# Bypass traffic on AWS WAF based on content-type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to bypass WAF on Cloudfront if the request is fore statics files like images?

This is a simple question, but one that has a big impact on operating cost. Because the charge of Cloudfront + WAF is performed by GB, so images have a high impact on cost, and there is no need to have a firewall.

Comment: This sounds like a question for the vendor, AWS.

Comment: I believe it is. But if someone know that it, or already set this customisation it helps.

Comment: @MateusSaggin there is no per GB charge for Amazon WAF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's no per-gigabyte charge. There's a $0.60 charge per million *requests*. https://aws.amazon.com/waf/pricing/
2. If you want to avoid that, set up a second CloudFront distribution without the WAF and use that one for static assets. It can have identical settings, or you can set the origin to point directly at your `images` subfolder if you have one. (This has the additional benefit of stopping someone from using the second distribution to bypass the WAF.)

Comment: @ceejayvoz and @michael - sqlbot, sorry about my mistake, it’s by request, that’s right. But I had around `500M visits` * `10 pageviews` * `150 requests` months, this is `750 billions requests` and a `U$450.000,00` month. This is extremely unviable. So what I need, is to host all files keeping the domain, but the statics ones out of WAF. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @MateusSaggin See #2 in my answer. Use a separate distribution for the static files.

Comment: (Also, 150 requests for every pageview is incredibly excessive in most cases, unless you're running a large photo gallery site or something. 750 billion requests is probably always going to be at least *somewhat* expensive, though.)

Comment: ceejayoz, we developed a ecommerce platform. So, yes, it has too many request, especially on category/search/department pages. We now that 750 billion request is expensive. But expend money with WAF on unnecessary files is stupid. So, if exists a way ok. Or, if not, we will build a CNAME that resolves to another Cloudfront, and all stores needs a subdomain to "host" static files.

Comment: The separate CNAME is the way to go here, I suspect. Something like `static.example.com` pointed at your static files directory.